# What's the meaning of this expression in Java?

Tags: java

I'm studying the book "The Java Tutorial" 6th edition.
I ran through this example:

```
public int indexOf(E e) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if(e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.net()))
            return it.previousIndex();
    return -1;
}
```

My question is: what's the precise meaning of the particular syntax used for the for-loop? And, what does it mean in the if condition the "?" and the ":"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is nothing to be fixed here.

Comment: Read about Ternary operator.

Comment: I'd like a hint to understand the meaning of the syntax. I don't think it's offtopic

Comment: First, you must study about `for` loop and how it works, next `if` condition and `ternary operator`.

Comment: Thank you, I read the meaning of the ternary operators. Now, the question is: how is it composed that particular for? I know about the classic for loop with the three conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (initialization ; condition ; incrementation) { ... }`
is a normal for-loop syntax. You can leave the incrementation part blank if you don't want it. But be careful as it may cause endless loops. Thats how your loop looks like - without the incrementation part.

`e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.net())` is a simple ternary operator:
`IF condition ? THEN : ELSE`

Rewritten it means something like this:

```
if(e == null) {
    return it.next == null 
}  else {
    return e.equals(it.net())
}
```

As it returns a boolean value the enclosing `if()` statement accepts it as condition.

Answer (score 1):

For easy example,

```
minVal = (a < b) ? a : b;
```

In this code, if the variable `a` is less than `b`, `minVal` is assigned the value of `a`; otherwise, `minVal` is assigned the value of `b`.

Your case

```
 if(e == null ? it.next() == null : e.equals(it.net()))
```

Meaning,

```
if e== null, 
   execute it.next() ==  null // compares and return true/false
else 
   execute e.equals(it.net()) // compares and return true/false
```